# Turning a Folder Into a Single File Without Zipping it?

Tags: c++, file, directory, archive

So my goal here is to created a self contained file that would include all the assets to load into a 3D scene. For instance there would be one text file detailing all the positions, rotations, scales, etc. of models and then folders with models and textures inside there. This wouldn't be hard to do in a folder, but for simplicity I want to have it all into one file, avoiding compressing it and uncompressing it. The reason why I don't want to compress and decompress it is to speed up loading times, because this is for a game.

Is there any possible way to do this? Or am I going to have to bite the bullet and make it into a zip.

Thanks.

Comment: a) Zip doesn´t require compression. b) Zip, 7z, Tar, Bzip2 etc.etc. There are many formats like this. c) You can always make your own binary file format. d) Other than general archive formats like mentioned in b, there are some etablished specialized 3D-model file formats too (and libs to save/load them) ...

Comment: Whatever you go with, if you will load resources on-demand then you want an archive format that has an index. Zip does; tar does not. This means with tar you would have to seek all over the place just to discover what resources you have and where they are.

Comment: @cdhowie Based on what everyone has said, I think I'm going to go with a low compressed zip.

Comment: Better go with maximum or no compression. You might even choose separately for different files, depending on how you use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ZIP without compression or TAR. But here's a better idea: compress it. CPU time is cheap. Disk transfers take forever. Most of the time, loading compressed data and decompressing it is faster than loading uncompressed data.

Comment: So you're saying loading in the compressed file and then uncompressing it is going to be faster than leaving it uncompressed?

Comment: Yes, with some fast algorithm that is true, specially with 3D models that have a very high compression ratio.

Comment: @BlueSpud Depending on your HDD and CPU, possible (and, as AdrianMaire said, the compression algo). Slower HDD and faster CPU will increase the benefit. SSDs and a Raspi on the other hand...

Comment: @AdrianMaire any suggestions on specific algorithms? I don't know a whole lot about file zipping.

Comment: @BlueSpud: No, I dont, but most library allow different levels of compression, take the lower just after no-compression. But also consider file formats like .3ds, .obj, etc.. they allow you to import 3D models directly from 3D modeling programs (which is a big benefit). Most of them provide libraries to open them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a ZIP file with no compression. ("Stored" mode.) There are also similar packaging archivers that are useful for creating a single archive from multiple files. TAR files on *nix systems are popular for this, and there are many others, as well.

Also, balance the amount of time that will be spend decompressing against the amount of time that will be spent loading an (uncompressed) file from disk. A lot of times, the disk read times for an uncompressed file are longer than the time that would be spent loading a compressed file and uncompressing it in memory.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but as I understand the question, BlueSpud seem to need something more like a file format.

Comment: Agreed. My point is that going ahead and using a ZIP file -- with compression -- may end up saving time because of the decreased disk I/O.

Comment: @AdrianMaire If zipping it uncompressed is just as fast as a folder, it will suit my needs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a Windows application, you can use user-defined resource statements in the .RC file for your EXE or included DLL(s) that will insert the data from the external files as binary  resources.  This is especially handy if you want to only distribute a single EXE file that relies on data contained in other files, or don't want to have the files you might otherwise archive and distribute with your app accessible/modifiable (without some work) by an end user.

It's extremely easy - the syntax is just

```
nameID typeID filename
```

for the resource file.  You can access the data using `::FindResource()` and `::LoadResource().`  MS docs for user-defined resources are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381054(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Unfortunately this is in Linux Mac and windows, so I have one project and don't want to make 3 projects to change it for each.

Answer (score 0):

The timing of the original question may be fortuitous.  It turns out that in the future the Find/Load resource approach I suggested won't be an option for us either (the code that I used it in before is going cross-platform), so I came up with a solution that may also work for you.  Full code is a bit much to post as an SO answer (but see my follow-on comment), although you can probably cook up a quick version of your own in no time.

Basically, I wrote a utility that just takes a basename for the output files as `argv[1]` ("*output-base-name*"), and `argv[2...(argc-1)]` are input files.  I open `output-base-name.cpp` and `output-base-name.h` for writing (will overwrite if they exist).

For each input file, the generator utility does this:

1: generates a variable-name-friendly identifier based on the filename ("*generated_name*")
2: reads the input file
3: dumps the following into `output-base-name.cpp`:

```
static uint8_t generated_name[] = {
    // Initialize with contents of input file as a bunch of 0xNN, 0xNN... values.
};
```

and into `output-base-name.h`, a corresponding

```
static const unsigned IDR_generated_name = N; // start at 0, see below re:range check
```

4: After the last input file, finishes up **`output-base-name.cpp`** with something like

```
static struct {
    unsigned       ID;
    unsigned       size;  // I assume you aren't trying to embed files >4GB!
    const uint8_t* data;
} 
fileData[] = {
   // one array element for each input file
   { IDR_generated_name,  sizeof(generated_name), generated_name },
   ... 
};

const uint8_t* getResourceData(unsigned ID){
    // a real version would do a safer lookup/range check of some sort based on ID
    return fileData[ID].data;
}

unsigned getResourceSize(unsigned ID){
    // a real version would do a safer lookup/range check of some sort based on ID
    return fileData[ID].size;
}
```

5: Finishes **`output-base-name.h`** with prototypes for whatever your "get" functions look like, e.g.

```
extern const uint8_t* getResourceData(unsigned ID);
extern unsigned getResourceSize(unsigned ID);
```

Just use `output-base-name.h` wherever you need to access the data and add `output-base-name.cpp` to your makefile or project (make it dependent on the binary input files,  using the generator utility in the build rule and `make` will automatically regenerate it for you when necessary).  If you want them in a dynamic lib of some sort, just add appropriate export attributes to your "get" functions.

Have the generator wrap your output in a namespace, throw together a class-based interface to it if you want to (or generate one instead of the example "get" functions), and you should be good.

This approach has several advantages over using an uncompressed zip file (or even the embedded resource approach I suggested for Windows targets):

1. It's a lot simpler to deal with in your application code - no reading of the zip directory, extracting file data, etc. is required.
2. No added reliance on another third-party lib for lookup/extraction of file data (assuming you don't roll your own zip library, which would be even more work)
3. All the resolution and lookup work is done for you - the addresses for each byte array will already be resolved by the linker if sticking the data into a static library or your executable, or by the OS loader if a shared library or DLL
4. You know the data will exist or your binary cannot run (not the case with zip lib approach, or even Find/LoadResource on Windows)
5. Data is a bit more inaccessible to (therefore safer from) Joe User, compared to a zip file
6. Should be faster than either the zip or Windows resource approach due to the pre-resolution of data addresses during the load process for the application
7. It can be also used for any form of relatively static data you want to ship with (or make available to) your app - just package files into a shared/dynamic library with the generator and use the generated exported accessor functions.  You can even create updated or completely new data packages later (after compilation/ship time) and load at runtime using config options.
8. It will work in older C++ compilers if necessary (or, sans generating any namespace or class wrappers, even plain-old-C)

This is only an example of the approach that I used, but it covers all the basics so if a solution sooner rather than later (again, see comment) is better for you, this might be enough (you'd want to range-check the values in the "get" functions - at least in debug builds, maybe use containers of some sort instead of using a c-style struct array, etc).

Comment: Follow-on comment referenced in answer (part 1):
Although full source is not posted in answer (for length + other reasons discussed in meta post [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278616/providing-a-follow-up-link-for-an-so-answer)), I'm almost done with a complete implementation that will be released as open source.  I'll be out of town for a few days, but I'll be cleaning up, completing and adding more capability to my quick-and-dirty/proof-of-concept version and posting it on my blog when I get back.

Comment: Follow-on part 2 (too long for just one):
When I post it, I'll be deleting these comment and adding a link to the source location in the answer, so if anyone's interested the full source, just "favorite" the original question and your favorites tab in your profile will then get highlighted when I post the link (probably a week or so from now).